# Retrofit 2 - How to know the response was from retrofit cache?

Tags: caching, realm, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I use reyrofit 2 + rxjava (android).
I'm updating realm database after request. The problem is it executes even the data was from retrofit cache.
How can I check the response was from cache or server returns 304 status and do not update DB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `Observable<Body>` into `Observable<Response<Body>>` and check your headers or http status code via its public methods. See [doc](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html)